# How do I make a list in a list from a text file?

Tags: python, list

I have text file in alphabetic order looking like this in Python:

At 210.001 \n
Au 196.9665 \n
B  10.81 \n
Ba 137.34 \n

I would like to have it sorted by numbers instead of letters. I was thinking that I could make a list of each row within a list and from there sort by index one? That also means that the space between the letters and the numbers need to be a ",".

Comment: What language do you want?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, Python!

Answer (score 0):

You can split it and then sort by an additional split:

```py
splitlist = mylist.split('\n') # Split at new line
splitlist.sort(key=lambda line:float(line.split()[-1])) # Inline sort
```

Now `splitlist` will be sorted by the last (second) column.

To break it down, `mylist.sort()` is an **inline** sort (it changes the order of the list without making a new one). Then you can specify a `key`. The `key` must be a callable that takes `key(item)`. So I made a `lambda` function to (1) split the line [`line.split()`], (2) take the last item of the split `[-1]` and then (3) convert it to `float()` so it can be compared

I hope this helps

#### Additional tip

(to try to address the comment)

You can also make a dictionary:

```
splitlines = [line.split() for line in splitlist]
atoms = {name:float(weight) for name,weight in splitlines}
```

Then you can query it by `atom['Na']` for example

Comment: Oh wow the sorting thing really worked! But later in I would like just call upon the atoms/the strings and the atom weight/the float. Is it possible now when I do not have the lists?

Comment: @J.Doe I added an additional tip that should help. In my original answer I assumed you wanted the lines. You could have just kept them split if you wanted the separately or, as I also suggest, use a dictionary to help speed it up

Comment: That was very useful! Although, if I really wanted it to be lists, how do I do?

Comment: The `splitlines` object in my edit is a list of lists from your data